# Using blade to view the navbar across all the the pages Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

So,I have a the navbar in my home page where all the module name gets listed from the database. Instead of re-writing the whole code to list module name in all page I decided to use `blade's` `@yeild()` functionality.

This is my home page Controller where I get all the module names and pass it to the homepage view like so

```
public function index()
    {
        $data = Module::get();

        return view("BaseView.home")->with('data',$data);
    }
```

This is my homepage view where I display all the modules and it's respective name in the navbar like so

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
        @foreach($data as $modules)
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                {{ $modules->module_name) }}<i class="plusMinus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                @foreach($modules->module_categories as $category)
                   <?php
                        $getModuleNameToLowerCase = strtolower($modules->module_name);
                        $getCategoryNameToLowerCase = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', strtolower($category->categories_name));
                    ?>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">{{ $category->categories_name }}</a>
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>

<div class="container-fluid">
    @yield('mainBody')
</div>
```

Now When I `extend` this in another view like so

```
@extends('BaseView.home')
```

I get `Undefined variable: data`.

Can someone help me/guide me on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Have a look at using a view composer: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#view-composers

Comment: Or you can manually pass additional data to a component.

Comment: So for other view you call other controller where you are not getting modules on $data. While loading home you are getting all models on $data variable and working fine. So make an separate HTML file for module and include in your master blade (home). You can pass module to each view by setting variable as $data on each controllers' constructors.

Comment: please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33254080/database-driven-menu-that-can-be-loaded-in-view/33255118#33255118

Answer (score 0):

In you controller, you need to pass modules to each view, because view does not keep the values after new request. For each request there must be modules ($data).
 
Remember, the data passed to `master blade` using one `controller method` will not work for another `controller method`, because every time each new request need all values of those variables again that are used in master and child blades.

Controller

```
//..............
//................. 
public function index()
{
    $data['modules'] = Module::get();
    //$data['other_data'] = User::get(); //To get other data and pass to your view
    return view("BaseView.home")->with('data',$data);
}

public function profilePage()
{
    $data['modules'] = Module::get();
    //$data['profile_detail'] = Profile::get(); //To get other data and pass to your view
    return view("BaseView.home")->with('data',$data);
}
//Something like this
```

But writing `$data['modules'] = Module::get();` for each controller method, you can write it inside your constructor of the your controller. This will be for all methods (Requests) .

```
public function __construct(){
    $data['modules'] = Module::get();   
}
public function index()
{
    //$data['other_data'] = User::get(); //To get other data and pass to your view
    return view("BaseView.home")->with('data',$data);
}

//................
//.................
```

And view:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
        <?php 
        if(isset($data['modules'])&&count($data['modules'])>0){
        ?>
        @foreach($data['modules'] as $modules)
        .............
        ..............

        @endforeach
        <?php 
        }
        else{
            echo "Modules are not available";
        }
        ?>
    </ul>

<div class="container-fluid">
    @yield('mainBody')
</div>
```

**The above is for your error message**, But if you want that modules to be available anywhere then you can use `session` or `creating helper`

Comment: This method is very inefficient as we fetch all the module category from the database each time a view is called. I just want it fetch one time and use around all the views in the application.

Comment: oh okay, At this time, in my mind only one method, store modules on session when first user visit your app. I mean when you place you first request just get all modules and store into session and use any where. You can encode all modules in JSON and store in session.

Comment: Another good way might be creating helper class, Look into creating and using helper class for system wide data.

Comment: Yea thanks! I will look into it :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing data on every view, use Providers boot method which triggers before loading any view and pass your default data on every view. simple.